# How to extract the anchor tag which is like this <a class="a-no-hover-decoration" ... >?

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So,

Let's say I am searching Google for "White Russian", As soon as we do that, we receive some model cards as shown in the image below,

[image: searching_white_russian_on_google_sample_pic]

Now, if you will look at the HTML's Inspector, we will get to see that those card's HREF is within an anchor tag and it's like the below image, (... denotes extra stuff)

[image: anchor tag image]

```html
<a class="a-no-hover-decoration" href="https://www.liquor.com/recipes/white-russian/" .....>
```

So, What i am interested is in extracting that href from such anchor tags if they exist for a search.

My Attempt,

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=White+Russian")
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all("a", {"class": "a-no-hover-detection"}) # this returns Nothing
```

I am kinda new to web-**scraping**, so will appreciate your help.

My second question is, How to detect that we have such model cards Vs when we don't have such cards for any given random search?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get correct response from Google's server, specify `User-Agent` HTTP header, and `hl=en` parameter (to get english results). Also, the class name is `a-no-hover-decoration`, not `a-no-hover-detection`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0"
}

params = {"q": "White Russian", "hl": "en"}

req = requests.get(
    "https://www.google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers
)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
for a in soup.find_all("a", {"class": "a-no-hover-decoration"}):
    print(a["href"])
```

Prints:

```
https://www.liquor.com/recipes/white-russian/
https://www.delish.com/cooking/recipe-ideas/a29091466/white-russian-cocktail-recipe/
https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/white-russian
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Understood my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You can also grab CSS selectors visually using [SelectorGadgets](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=white russian', headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
# select() method: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class
for result in soup.select('.cv2VAd .a-no-hover-decoration'):
  link = result['href']
  print(link)
```

Output:

```
https://www.liquor.com/recipes/white-russian/
https://www.delish.com/cooking/recipe-ideas/a29091466/white-russian-cocktail-recipe/
https://www.kahlua.com/en-us/drinks/white-russian/
```

---

Alternatively, you can do it using [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api). It's a paid API with a free trial of 5,000 searches.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "White Russian",
  "google_domain": "google.com",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results['recipes_results']:
  link = result['link']
  print(link)
```

Output:

```
https://www.liquor.com/recipes/white-russian/
https://www.delish.com/cooking/recipe-ideas/a29091466/white-russian-cocktail-recipe/
https://www.kahlua.com/en-us/drinks/white-russian/
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.